# How to add a node at the end of the list?

Tags: java

I am trying to add a node at the end of the list.Is this code is right?

```
public void insertLast(int id,double dd)
{
    Link current=First;
    while(current!=null)
    {
        current=current.next;
    }

    Link temp=new Link(id,dd);
    temp.next=current;
    current=temp;
}
```

Comment: After the `while` loop completes, what will the value of `current` be?

Comment: current will be null

Comment: temp is a new reference it will have some address now current null value is passed to temp.....and current value change to temp

Comment: If you want to find the end of the list, that would be when `current.next == null`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the loop condition `current!=null` to

`current.next != null`

because like it's been pointed out, `current` will be `null` after the loop ends and you want `current` to be the last node in the list. However, if you choose to do this, then you also need to do a check at the beginning of the method to see if `First` is `null`, because if it is then you loop will throw an exception since you can't check the next element of a `null` object.

```
public void insertLast(int id,double dd)
{
    Link current=First;
    if(current == null) {
        First = new Link(id,dd);
        First.next = null;
        return;
    }
    while(current.next != null)
    {
        current=current.next;
    }

    Link temp = new Link(id,dd);
    current.next = temp;
    temp.next = null;
}
```

Comment: i want temp to be the last node.....

Comment: @Aaakash exactly, so when `current` becomes the last node, you set `current.next` to the new node. Check my edit.

Comment: I still have a doubt sir....

Comment: @Aakash what is your doubt?

Comment: @Johnny Mopp thank you sir, I can't believe I didn't catch that

Comment: solved....thanks Chris Gong Sir

Comment: And @Johnny Mopp Sir

Comment: @Aakash No problem. if you found the answer helpful then don't forget to accept or upvote the answer. Good luck coding!